# Render_template or redirect not working in Flask

Tags: javascript, post, flask

I am trying to get data from JS file through a POST request. I am able to receive the data . But after processing when I try to render the data, I am unable to render new information.

Flask template looks like this:

```
@app.route('/next',methods=['POST','GET'])
def next():
    if request.method=="POST":
        value=request.form['data']
        clicks=request.form['cnt']
        clicks=int(clicks)
        list_val,count=search_data_offset(value,clicks*1000)
        if(list_val):
            print(count)
            return render_template('search.html',list_val=list_val,count=count)
    return render_template('index.html',message="No records found. Please refresh your search")
```

Code works till print statement. Count value will get displayed on the console. But render_template is not working. I even notice that when a POST request is made there is no change in URI on the webpage.

JS which makes POST request looks like this

```
var count=0
$("i").click(function(){
    count=count+1
    console.log(count)
    $.post('/next',{
        data:location.search,
        cnt:count
    });     
});
```

HTML which triggers JS is the below statement

```
<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
```

Console prints the count information correctly. But render_template is not working.

Comment: When you say code works until print statement, that would indicate you're getting an error?  Can you look at your Flask server console/terminal and include the error-- it will point you to the problem area.

Comment: Please enable debug and add the console output in the question.